# Crontab sets 18:00 to 09:00

Tags: unix, cron

I just want to set a crontab using that I want to make a program run at every 15 minutes 
from 18:00 to 09:00 
I have given this statement and waited but I don't think it is working

```
*/15 18-9 * * 1-6  Program_name
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have wrongly selected that ,I apology

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don’t think ranges can wrap around like that. Specify the hour as `0-9,18-23` instead.

Comment: This is fine , is there any way that we can say it in a single expression itself , ( note : your idea is fine )

Comment: The problem is that 18-9 spans multiple days. You gave * for the weekday, but what if someone said 1? Should cron do the job on Sunday evenings and Monday mornings, or on Sunday evenings and Sunday mornings? That's why overnight ranges aren't allowed: they are ambiguous.