# jenkins cron job schedule

Tags: cron, jenkins, job-scheduling

I wasn't sure how to schedule a job to run from 10 PM to 7 AM (the next day). I was thinking if something like below would work

```
0 22-8 * * *
```

Thanks

Comment: I havent.. becuase its on prod servers and cannot get things going wrong. Thats why I just wanna confirm if something like this is feasible

Comment: I don't think it works. 

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592185/crontab-sets-1800-to-0900

Comment: Could you please upvote and close the question then?